# How many random draws needed to sample a uniform space?

Tags: probability, python, coupon-collector-problem

I am looking for a way to estimate how many random draws took place to produce a produce a known number of unique results. I'm sampling a uniform distribution.

For example, if there were a lottery with 6 picks of numbers 1-10 (1,000,000 possible combinations), and the lottery published how many unique combinations were picked every day, how could I estimate how many tickets were sold?

Here's a similar example in python in case it's useful:

```
import random
size = 1000000
numbers = []
for i in range(500000):
    numbers.append(random.randint(0, size))

print(f'Size of pool: {size}, Unique results: {len(set(numbers))}')
```

This typically yields something like: `Size of pool: 1000000, Unique results: 393485`. I can observe that I have ~390,000 unique results from a pool of 1,000,000.

So, I know the size of the total pool and I can measure the number of unique results. How do I estimate the number of random draws that occurred, given the size of the pool and the number of unique results?

Comment: Can't do it without knowing the seed.  Easier to count the sand on the beach, the stars in the sky.  A decent random number generator doesn't repeat in 2^19937 draws.  That is 10^6001 or so.   There are merely 10^11 stars in the milky way galaxy.  You aren't going to have to have 2^19937 tries to get the same unique-count, but you are going to have to do more than a few things to get into your neighborhood.

Comment: I think there may have been a misunderstanding - I'm considering a problem where I know the size of the random space. For example, I'm looking to estimate how many random draws were picked out of a pool of 1,000,000 if I know that there were 390,000 unique results for example.

Comment: This is a variation on the [tag:coupon-collector-problem]. Lots of threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector%27s+problem

Comment: This does seem to be largely of the same class as the coupon collector problem! The solutions that I'm finding are all for estimating how many draws needed to sample all of the set... how does one adapt that to sampling part of the set?

Comment: If we simplify the task to flips of a fair coin, then for a large number of flips there is a very high probability that we have at least 1 T and at least one H, so the only data we have is that there are 2 outcomes and we've observed both outcomes. We won't know if there were 2 or 2,000,000 flips in total, and there's not any useful information to assign probabilities to the total number of flips.

Comment: On the coupon-collector problem: there's also some good resources on math.SE, including derivation of the distribution of the number of draws to complete a set, for example. Some of that information will be useful for this question.